# Is there a form field in Django that allows you to enter multiple values one at a time?

Tags: django

I could also use a `TextField`, but that's not ideal from UX point of view. I would like to know if there's a field that allows the user to enter **multiple custom strings** (**not from a pre-defined list of options**), one at a time, where, to enter a string, one needs to press enter, these values are then passed as a list of strings (or other types) to the model, which defines an `ArrayField`.

I've searched for some time, but I couldn't find it. I'm not really an expert in Django, but I suppose such a field must exist.

If not, I suppose I could create a custom form field that does that.

Here's what I mean.

[image]

In the example, `1` was written, then the user pressed ENTER, and the option was added; then the same thing happened to add `2`; the important thing to note is that `1` and `2` do not come from a predefined set of values, but were custom strings entered by the user, which can also be removed after having been entered.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got your question right, you want a `ArrayField` for your form. Take a look at [SplitArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#splitarrayfield):

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.forms import SplitArrayField


class SthForm(forms.Form):
    arr_field = SplitArrayField(forms.CharField(max_length=100))
```

Comment: That's not really what I want. With `SplitArrayField` (I've just tried it), you need to specify a fixed size of rows. I don't know in advance the number of strings, but I could set a limit. So, something like  `SplitArrayField` but with a variable number of strings.